# Setting the line width in a smart gwt facetchart

Tags: charts, smartgwt

I'm unsing the FacetChart widget to display several graphs at the same time. The default line width while using the ChartType.LINE is quite big. It is hard to differentiate graphs with nearly similar values.
Is there a way to set a smaller line width?

Answer (score 1):

Using FusionCharts, it is possible to set the line width by just setting "lineThickness" attribute. Also, it supports various attributes to  configure how your line plot will appear on the chart. It can be shown as dashed lines, lines plots using various colors etc. Give a TRY!!!